# Python re: How to match any numbers even those with comma & decimal?

Tags: python, python-re

I want to match any numbers that could have decimal, comma or simply whole number. I tried the below, but my regular expression  can't match if the number have > 2 comma.

Thank you

```
import re

string1= "6,111,123,999 5,450,900 10.32 OCT21  Dec 31, 2019"

num=re.findall(r'\b\d+[.,]*\d+[,]*d*\b', string1)

Result:

['6,111,123', '999', '5,450,900', '10.32', '31', '2019']

Desired Outcome --> ['6,111,123,999', '5,450,900', '10.32', '31', '2019']
```

Comment: try `[\d.,]+` ...

Comment: this regex is working `([0-9,.]+)` but i didnt cant make dont catch `,` after 31

Comment: Match any string consisting of digits, commas and points and use a lookahead to ensure that it contains at least one digit. Alternatively, if suitable, write it so that it starts with a digit, then digits, commas or points follow, finally a digit at the end.

Comment: @GhostOps This would also match `,,..,,,.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### matching all numbers

You could use `\d(?:[\d,.]*\d+)?`

```
string1= "6,111,123,999 5,450,900 10.32 OCT21  Dec 31, 2019 1"

import re
re.findall(r'\d(?:[\d,.]*\d+)?', string1)
```

output: `['6,111,123,999', '5,450,900', '10.32', '21', '31', '2019', '1']`

#### matching only numbers that are independent words

Use `\b[\d,.]*\d+\b`:

```
string1= "6,111,123,999 5,450,900 10.32 OCT21  Dec 31, 2019 1"

import re
re.findall(r'\b[\d,.]*\d+\b', string1)
```

output: `['6,111,123,999', '5,450,900', '10.32', '31', '2019', '1']`

###### edit: matching only space, end of string, or comma as separator

```
string1= "6,111,123,999 5,450,900 10.32 1a2 1-2 OCT21  Dec 31, 2019 1"

import re
re.findall(r'(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\s))[\d,.]*\d+(?=$|\s|,)', string1)
```

output: `['6,111,123,999', '5,450,900', '10.32', '31', '2019', '1']`

Comment: Thanks a lot! \b[\d,.]*\d+\b works except when there is numbers with dash in-between like 1-2. The pattern extracts '1' and '2'. How do I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: @Peter check the update, but now you'll have to handle the separators you want or don't want manually

Answer (score 0):

Try `(?:[\d]+[.,]?\b)+`

It matches any numbers that could have decimal, comma or simply if its a whole number

Code:

```py
import re

string1= "6,111,123,999 5,450,900 10.32 OCT21  Dec 31, 2019"
num = re.findall(r'(?:\b[\d]+[.,]?\b)+', string1)

print(num)
```

Outputs:

```py
['6,111,123,999', '5,450,900', '10.32', '31', '2019']
```

[**Regex101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/xvn4cA/2)

Tell me if its okay for you...

Answer (score 0):

here would be my quick fix to your desired outcome which is a mixture of regex (which I find creates a lot of code noise) and some simple object manipulations. Not pretty overall but does it:

```
import re

string_one = "6,111,123,999 5,450,900 10.32 OCT21  Dec 31, 2019"

num=[re.findall(r'^[0-9,.]+', el.rstrip(',')) for el in string_one.split()]

# give a proper result
result = [item for sublist in num for item in sublist]

print(result)
# ['6,111,123,999', '5,450,900', '10.32', '31', '2019']
```